# Ubuntu ; Python3 - Textract installation - Codec error with Ebooklib & pocketsphinx

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, package, codec

Ubuntu 16.04 - Python 3.6

After getting this error:

```
textract Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/tmp/pip-build-xxxx/EbookLib/
```

with message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 
1671: character maps to <undefined>
```

which can be solved using the last version of textract:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract.git@master
```

see [link](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract/issues/194) pmahend1 first comment

I'm facing the same issue with pocketsphinx.

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/tmp/pip-build-xxxx/pocketsphinx/
```

With a message codec error pointing on line 189 of setup.py file.

Did someone face the same issue? How have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it seems to work:

**Download Pocketsphinx-0.1.3**

```
wget "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/5f/a968e5d53d25e32deb78c3e169fd8612ecf53cc76e32cb40e19be3"
```

**Extract Pocketsphinx-0.1.3**

```
tar -jxvf pocketsphinx-0.1.3.tar.bz2
```

**Change Pocketsphinx-0.1.3 setup.py**

```
cd pocketsphinx-0.1.3
nano setup.py
```

=> Change line 189 to add after READ.rst *, encoding="utf-8"*)

**Install Pocketsphinx-0.1.3**

```
pip3 install .
sudo python3.6 setup.py install
```

**Download textract**

```
git clone git://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract.git
nano textract/requirements/python
```

**Comment pocketsphinx==0.1.3 line**

**Install textract**

```
pip3 install .
```

(in the folder containing setup.py)